# How do I access getStringArray with a variable

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I'm sure there's a perfect fine way to do this much better, but basically what I want is to create 2-dim array via strings.xml.

ie. I have a main category:

```
<string-array name="main_categories">
    <item>index_etf</item>
    <item>region_etf</item>
    <item>commodity_etf</item>
</string-array>
```

and a bunch of subcategories:

```
<string-array name="index_etf">
    <item>DOW</item>
    <item>NASDAQ</item>
</string-array>
```

instead of doing it hardcoded like:

```
    MainCategoryArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_categories);
    IndexETFArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.index_etf);
    ...
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
    MainCategoryArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_categories);

    loop through the main array and populate the sub categories
```

Not sure if I can access the `getStringArray` with an `int` variable based on the content of the MainCategoryArray, is there?

Any better approach to build a multi-dimensional based on strings.xml? Sorry, new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

> Variable declaration

```
private final static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private ArrayList<String> mainCategoryArray;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> categoryArrays  = new ArrayList<>();
```

> Usage

```
 mainCategoryArray = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_categories)));
    for(String mainCategory : mainCategoryArray){
        try {
            categoryArrays.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(getResources().getIdentifier(mainCategory, "array", getPackageName())))));
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e){
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }
```

> Sample strings.xml array

```
<string-array name="main_categories">
    <item>index_etf</item>
    <item>region_etf</item>
    <item>commodity_etf</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="index_etf">
    <item>DOW</item>
    <item>NASDAQ</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="region_etf">
    <item>DOW</item>
    <item>NASDAQ</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="commodity_etf">
    <item>DOW</item>
    <item>NASDAQ</item>
</string-array>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @Mairyu If you like the answer, please adopt it too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use qualifiers on resources so android itself choose appropriate resources based on the qualifiers. For example you can have `values-small` for small screens and `values-large` for large screen and `values` for other screen sizes. You can see all available qualifiers [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources).